# Android error intent pick image from gallery depending on path

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-manifest

I have a function which tries to get the image from the image path, it works depending on were the image is.

For some reason, it works fine from this location

```
/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0082.jpg
```

but these locations does not work

```
/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20150315_133312.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20150825_161105.jpg
```

It results in a blank thumbnail and an error when i try to upload the image from file path.

Here is my Intent for picking the photo:

```
//Camera Application for existing Photo
public void btnExistingPhotoClicked(View v) {
    //invoke the intent to get an image from the phone
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);//one can be replaced with any action code


}
```

And here is the actual onActivityResult which picks it up, put it in a thumbnail and then display the imagepath in a Textview

```
case 1:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    //function for a selected image
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    mImageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                    Toast.makeText(this, mImageView.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", mImageView.toString());

                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imgurl = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    //The imageview is set, this is the small preview in the app
                    TextView tximgurl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtImgUrl);
                    tximgurl.setText(imgurl);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", imgurl.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(this, imgurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
                break;
```

Comment: Maybe you need different privileges to access these new folders?

Comment: I have<br>     <!-- Whats needed for using the camera --><br> 
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" /><br> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storages" /><br> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><br> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><br>

Comment: Is the emulated path in internal storage or in external?

Comment: @acostela It's on the Internal memory

Comment: You should change EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI with INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. Hope that helps

Comment: If that works tell me and I will put it as a formal answer

Comment: @acostela it does not work. works the same way as it did before.